# "Get-Package *notepad* | Uninstall-Package -Force" not working

Tags: powershell, nuget-package, uninstallation

I'm opening `PowerShell` as Administrator.

I run:

```
Get-Package *notepad*
```

And PowerShell shows me ***Notepad++ (32-bit x86)***

I then run:

```
Get-Package *notepad* | Uninstall-Package -Force
```

And PowerShell is not uninstalling Notepad++

I tried with a few programs, they are still all installed. Why?

**EDIT:** as you can see @m0lochwalker PowerShell is acting like the program was uninstalled.

[image]

Try on your environment, nothing gets uninstalled.

@Ranadip Dutta: `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product` works for 32-bit only and doesn't return Notepad++ if it's 64-bit; Basically it doesn't return any 64-bit at all:

[image]

I need something more comprehensive that could work both with 32-bit and 64-bit

Comment: Use something like $program = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product | ? {$_.Name -eq “your program”} ...then $program.uninstall()

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? or just directly it is giving the control back in the shell without anything ?

Comment: I think this is a bug/feature of uninstall-package. If the provider name is Programs, then the cmdlet will not uninstall it. It means you did not use the package manager to install the program initially

Comment: Francesco - your comments about the Win32 _Product class are incorrect. Why don’t you try my command in your environment.

Comment: @m0lochwalker: I tried your command and you can see by the picture, is not working. Try to run `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product | select Name` and you will discover that a lot of your programs are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product` is an old dinosaur that must die.

`Get-Package` is probably broken and I flagged it to the [official Microsoft repository](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/3723)

In the meantime [Mike F Robbins](https://mikefrobbins.com/) helped me understanding how rotten `Win32_Product` is and he drove me to this [awesome post](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/07/27/gathering-installed-software-using-powershell.aspx) where you can copy paste the code into a `test.ps1` file and install it into your PowerShell system by doing `. .\test.ps1`

Now you have installed the `Get-Software` method that will help you dive into your programs at a light speed (not like `Win32_Product`).

Now I can use:

`Get-Software | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "*Notepad*" } | Format-Table`

to see Notepad++ and I can uninstall it using the `UninstallString`

[image]

Is not what I wanted but is the closest working thing that I found.
Feel free to add a new reply if you find a better one.

**EDIT:** There was indeed a bug and Microsoft is resolving it.

For now you can use:

```
get-package *notepad* |% { & $_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]}
```